# Sprint-boot automatically shutting down after starting server

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-boot

I am trying to create a simple Spring-boot app for practice. However it seems the server starts but then immediately shuts down. This problem has persisted for days and I'm unsure how to fix.

The entire console output I have displayed below. When I check `localhost:8080` it shows nothing.

HelloSpringApplication.java

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class HelloSpringApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(HelloSpringApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

pom.xml

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

console

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.0.0.RELEASE)

2018-03-26 17:34:20.469  INFO 5561 --- [           main] com.example.demo.HelloSpringApplication  : Starting HelloSpringApplication on Aarons-MacBook-Pro.local with PID 5561 (/Users/aaron/Documents/workspace-sts-3.9.3.RELEASE/HelloSpringApplication/target/classes started by aaron in /Users/aaron/Documents/workspace-sts-3.9.3.RELEASE/HelloSpringApplication)
2018-03-26 17:34:20.472  INFO 5561 --- [           main] com.example.demo.HelloSpringApplication  : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2018-03-26 17:34:20.512  INFO 5561 --- [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@691a7f8f: startup date [Mon Mar 26 17:34:20 CDT 2018]; root of context hierarchy
2018-03-26 17:34:21.021  INFO 5561 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2018-03-26 17:34:21.030  INFO 5561 --- [           main] com.example.demo.HelloSpringApplication  : Started HelloSpringApplication in 0.743 seconds (JVM running for 1.141)
2018-03-26 17:34:21.032  INFO 5561 --- [       Thread-2] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Closing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@691a7f8f: startup date [Mon Mar 26 17:34:20 CDT 2018]; root of context hierarchy
2018-03-26 17:34:21.034  INFO 5561 --- [       Thread-2] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Unregistering JMX-exposed beans on shutdown
```

Comment: You should check if port 8080 is available for Tomact to use.
Try adding `server.port=5000` (or any other port) in the application.properties file located in "resources" folder and see if that works for you.

Comment: I added the port to the properties file and still no dice. I can boot my own tomcat server in the servers tab and I can venture to `localhost:8080` and see a 404 error

Answer (score 3):

That output looks similar to the output of using `spring-boot-starter` not `spring-boot-starter-web` which has an embedded tomcat server. Ensure that you are using that dependency in your current `pom.xml`. Then use `mvn clean install` to ensure the dependencies are installed correctly and then run the spring app with `mvn spring-boot:run`.

You can initialize a spring project with [start.spring.io](https://start.spring.io/), this will provide a zip with a pre-configured empty project, don't forget to select `Web` dependency.

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that the version of spring-boot-starter and spring-boot-web are compatible in the pom.xml

Answer (score 0):

Just run the  `mvn clean install` and `mvn spring-boot:run` and see if there is any stack trace at console which can help to find the reason.. Moreover verify pom.xml build config as

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```